# How to split strings at specific intervals to arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split

How to split strings at specific intervals to arrays in Javascript?

For example: split this string into 4 characters (including space and characters)

`this is an example should be split,numbers(123),space,characters also included`

to

```
this ------> 1st array
 is  ------> 2nd array
 an  ------> 3rd array
exam ------> 4th array
ple  ------> 5th array
shou ------> 6th array     ............ etc till.....
..ed ------> last array
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var foo = "this is an example should be split,numbers(123),space,characters also included"; 
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
        if (i % 4 == 0 && i != 0)
            arr.push(foo.substring(i - 4, i));
        if (i == foo.length - 1)
            arr.push(foo.substring(i - (i % 4), i+1));          
    }
    document.write(arr);
    console.log(arr);
```

Comment: i am new to javascript, so can you please edit the code so that we can see the output in window (using document.write())

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that splits your string into chunks of whatever size you want:

```
function splitN(s, n) {
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i+=4) {
        output.push(s.substr(i, 4));
    }
    return(output);
}
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JvabJ/

Answer (score 0):

Change the "4"'s to "n"'s in the above code:

```
function splitN(s, n) {
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i+=n) {
        output.push(s.substr(i, n));
    }
    return(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` along with a regex:

```js
console.log("this is an example should be split,numbers(123),space,characters also included".match(/.{1,4}/g));
```